# How do I graph multiple columns on the Y-axis? (MS Chart Controls)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, microsoft-chart-controls

Trying to follow this example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/11/25/getting-started-with-the-asp-net-3-5-chart-control.aspx

I have a database with 4 columns, 3 of the columns are int (1-10) and the other is a "DateTime". I am trying to graph the 3 columns vs the DateTime(X-axis) on one line chart.

To add more than one y axis value I go to the Series property -> YValueMembers (notice the plural) and enter my 3 columns of the database (followed by commas) that I want on the Y axis.....but doesn't seem to work.

I get a run time error saying only 1 column is allowed on the Y axis.

> Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y
>   values can be set for this data
>   series.

How do I get all 3 columns vs the 4th column on one line chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

Properties (of the chart) -> Series (click on ellipse) -> Add a new series for each element on the Y-axis, using the same X-axis.