# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to bind multiple series to MS Chart

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, mschart

I am trying to bind a `DataTable` with a MS Chart. The Chart contains two series, that are two columns of the `DataTable`. I am using VB in Visual Studio 2010. Here is my code:

```
Public tableTempJDL As DataTable = New DataTable("TempJDL")    
'tableTempJDL is then filled

With Me.ChartBHKW
    .DataSource = tableTempJDL

    .Series(0).Name = oGebäude.Art
    .Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline
    .Series(1).Name = oBHKW.Modell
    .Series(1).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline

    .Series(0).XValueMember = Convert.ToString(tableTempJDL.Columns("Stunden"))
    .Series(0).YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(tableTempJDL.Columns("PthObjekt"))

    .Series(1).XValueMember = Convert.ToString(tableTempJDL.Columns("Stunden"))
    .Series(1).YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(tableTempJDL.Columns("PthBHKW"))

    .DataBind() '<-- ArgumentOutOfRangeException
End With
```

I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error: "Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series". And this even though I have [two series in my Chart settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231547/how-do-i-graph-multiple-columns-on-the-y-axis-ms-chart-controls).

I would like to avoid to [build the chart myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887292/asp-net-mvc-3-mschart-error-only-1-y-values-can-be-set-for-this-data-series), and I really need two series, not [two points for each XValue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/5caa51ae-9f5f-4c77-a272-33f837bbf8d1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is actually perfectly ok, except for the fact that the column "PthObjekt" does not exist.

I just find strange to get an error at the DataBind saying that I can't have a more than one series, instead of an error at the line

```
.Series(0).YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(tableTempJDL.Columns("PthObjekt"))
```

I don't understand how this line can be executed without error... Anyways.